# Script needs to read echoed line

Tags: shell, shell-script, pipe, stdout

So, I need to write a Bourne-shell script, where my script has to work with the line, that was just echoed to stdout - e.g.:

```
echo *something* | myscript.sh [parametres...]
```

This may be a basic thing, what I might have missed during my studies. I would include my attempts, but they are nowhere near the solution.
Anyway, any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key thing to be aware of here is that children inherit the STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR file descriptors of their parent. Meaning if you launch a script with STDIN connected to the STDOUT from another process (a pipe, such as your example), then anything launched by that script will also have it's STDIN connected to that same STDOUT from the other process.

Meaning if you do `echo foo | ./myscript.sh` where `myscript.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e 's/foo/bar/'
```

then `sed` will read from the `echo foo` and write to STDOUT (which will be connected to your TTY since it wasn't redirected when `myscript.sh` was launched).
Example:

```
$ echo foobar | ./myscript.sh
barbar
```

So how you use this depends on what you want to do. If you simply want to capture the input into a variable, you can use the `read` builtin to do this.
For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS= read -rd '' foo
echo "foo=<$foo>"
```

Which results in:

```
$ echo -e 'hello\nworld' | ./myscript.sh
foo=<hello
world>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo " foo bar " | {
# ...
IFS= read -r line
echo "$line"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard output of the left-hand side of the pipe is connected to the standard input of the right-hand side of the pipe. In your example, the output from `echo` becomes the input to `myscript.sh`.

If you want to store the whole output of `echo` into a variable, you can use a command substitution with `cat`.

```
whole_input=$(cat)
```

This strips off newlines at the end of the input.

You can also use the `read` builtin if you want to read one line at a time. Note that plain `read` splits the line into fields and uses backslash continuations; to read one line without additional complications, use `IFS= read -r`:

```
IFS= read -r first_line
IFS= read -r second_line
```